# Using predicates to filter out sources when doing a query

Tags: ios, nspredicate, healthkit

I'm trying to make an HKStatisticsQuery on step count, with a predicate that dismisses user-entered values.

I found out there were 2 differences between user-entered values and passively-logged values:

**Source:**
-passively logged values have "A's iPhone" for the source
-user-entered values have "Health" for the source

**'Was User Entered' metadata key:**
-passively logged don't have the metadata key at all
-user-entered values have a 'Was User Entered' metadata key set to true

I've tried this predicate, in an attempt to only get data that had 'Was User Entered' set to false:
`HKQuery.predicateForObjectsWithMetadataKey(HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered, allowedValues: [false])`

I got no results, and someone helped me realize that the metadata key doesn't even exist if it's passively logged (kind of redundant...)

Given the above differences, does anyone know of any other way to extract passively-logged data? I was thinking along the lines of

`NSPredicate(format: "%K != %@", HKPredicateKeyPathSource, "Health")//crash`

This predicate did not work and crashed my program when I executed my query.

Does anyone know why it crashes, or if there is a better way to achieve my goal of weeding out the data that is user-entered?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, please see my answer below and please accept if it works for you. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Your crash could be probably due to the fact that currently, only the "=" and "IN" operators are supported for predicates filtering HKSamples by source

You could use a source query first to pull out all the sources and ignore the health app source (which has a bundle identifier of **com.apple.Health**), by using the following code:

```
- (void)fetchSources 
{
    NSMutableArray *dataSources = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    HKQuantityType *stepsCount = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount];
    HKSourceQuery *sourceQuery = [[HKSourceQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:stepsCount
                                                           samplePredicate:nil
                                                         completionHandler:^(HKSourceQuery *query, NSSet *sources, NSError *error)
                                                         {
                                                             for (HKSource *source in sources)
                                                             {
                                                                 if (![source.bundleIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.apple.Health"])
                                                                 {
                                                                     [dataSources addObject:source];
                                                                 }
                                                             }
                                                         }];
    [self.healthStore executeQuery:sourceQuery];
}
```

Once you have all the other sources other than the Health App, use a source predicate to pull data for all the other sources:

```
NSPredicate *sourcesPredicate = [HKQuery predicateForObjectsFromSources:[NSSet setWithArray:self.dataSources]]
```

Hope this helps.